# Avoiding double SELECT/INSERT by INSERT'ing placeholder

Tags: postgresql, go, concurrency

Is it possible to perform a query that will `SELECT` for some values and if those values do not exist, perform an `INSERT` and return the very same values - in a single query?

Background:

I am writing an application with a large deal of concurrency. At one point a function will check a database to see if a certain key value exists using `SELECT`. If the key exists, the function can safely exit. If the value does not exist, the function will perform a REST API call to capture the necessary data, then INSERT the values into the database.

This works fine until it is run concurrently. Two threads (I am using Go, so goroutines) will each independently run the `SELECT`. Since both queries report that the key does not exist, both will independently perform the REST API call and both will attempt to `INSERT` the values.

Currently, I avoid double-insertion by using a duplicate constraint. However, I would like to avoid even the double API call by having the first query SELECT for the key value and if it does not exist, INSERT a placeholder - then return those values. This way, subsequent SELECT queries report that the key value already exists and will not perform the API calls or `INSERT`.

In Pseudo-code, something like this:

```
SELECT values FROM my_table WHERE key=KEY_HERE; 
if found;
   RETURN SELECTED VALUES;
if not found:
   INSERT values, key VALUES(random_placeholder, KEY_HERE) INTO table;
   SELECT values from my_table WHERE key=KEY_HERE;
```

The application code will insert a random value so that a routine/thread can determine if it was the one that generated the new `INSERT` and will subsequently go ahead and perform the Rest API call.

This is for a Go application using the `pgx` library.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a stored procedure and it would be a single query for the client to execute.  PostgreSQL, of course, would still execute multiple statements.  PostgreSQL insert statement can return values with the returning keyword, so you may not need the 2nd select.

Answer (score 0):

Lock the table in an appropriate [lock mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html).

For example in the strictest possible mode `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

LOCK elbat
     IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE id = 1;

-- if there wasn't any row returned make the API call and
INSERT INTO elbat
            (id,
             <other columns>)
            VALUES (1,
                    <API call return values>);

COMMIT;
-- return values the to the application
```

Once one transaction has acquired the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, no other transaction isn't even reading from the table until the acquiring transaction ends. And `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` won't be granted unless there are no other (even weaker) locks. That way the instance of your component that gets the lock first will do the check and the `INSERT` if necessary. The other one will be blocked in the meantime and the time it finally gets access, the `INSERT` has already been done in the first transaction, it need not make the API call anymore (unless the first one fails for some reason and rolled back).

If this is too strict for your use case, you may need to find out which lock level might be appropriate for you. Maybe, if you can make any component accessing the database (or at least the table) cooperative (and it sounds like you can do this), even advisory locks are enough.